# Unit testing angular2 @input couldn't pass data

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I have declared a component like this

```
export class Component {

  private selectedFieldType: string;
  private enableAddCheck: boolean = false;

  @Input('itemX') item;
}
```

and i have a html for two binding like this

```
Field : <input [(ngModel)]="item.fieldLabel" type="text" class="input-bars">
```

So i have created the unit testing code like this to check the two way binding like this

```
beforeEach(async(() => {


    // refine the test module by declaring the test component
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [Component , DND_DIRECTIVES],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true },
         DND_PROVIDERS ]
    })

    // create component and test fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component );

    // get test component from the fixture
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;



  }));

  it('To check fieldLabel to way binding from inputbox to data', () => {

    comp.item = {
      fieldLabel: 'text'
    };

    comp.ngOnInit();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let fieldTypeInput: HTMLInputElement;

    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

    fieldTypeInput = input[0].nativeElement;
    fieldTypeInput.value = 'field';

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.item.fieldLabel).toBe('field');

  });
```

But it's giving 'fieldLabel' undefined error for me.

How to pass the data to @input in my component through the unit test??

Comment: First of all, your given component doesn't implement NgOnInit interface.

Comment: Ok so how to pass the data to @input item

Comment: I said, that the example that you provided has an error, Where's the NgOnInit?

Comment: I'm not using it in my conponent

Comment: Why are you calling  comp.ngOnInit(); explicitely? I think this should be automatically called by angular 2 component lifecycle (if correctly used as Fals pointed out) and not by you

Comment: Actually i'm not using ngOnInit in my actual component. So without using the comp.ngOnInit i want to pass the data.

Answer (score 1):

After you change manually change the input value

```
fieldTypeInput.value = 'field';
```

you still need to dispatch the input event. It does not happen just because you change the value. The event is what Angular listens for in order to get the new value to process

```
import {dispatchEvent} from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util';

fieldTypeInput.value = 'field';
dispatchEvent(fieldTypeInput, 'input');
```

Also, as the event processing is asynchronous, you need to wait for it stablize. To do that, you can use `fixture.whenStable`, but then you also need to make the test `async`

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('..', async(() => {
  ...

  fieldTypeInput.value = 'field';
  dispatchEvent(fieldTypeInput, 'input');

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // do expectations here
  })
})
```

Comment: It's not working the error is coming because the data i pass like comp.item = {
      fieldLabel: 'text'
    }; didn't get passed to it